# Return Type of a method while returning multiple column in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on MVC in asp.net c# with using entity framework.(edmx file). I am having problem while returning multiple columns using LINQ query. My query is working fine, the only problem is with return type of method.

```
public List<string> searchcollege(string prefix)
{
  try
  {
    List<string> clglist = new List<string>(from a in objYaphie.TblYP_CollegeProfile 
                                            where a.SchoolName.StartsWith(prefix) 
                                            select a.CollegeId,a.SchoolName);
    return clglist;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.Write(e);
  }
  return null;  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What I want to know is that what should be the return type of the method in the above code block. Since I am retrieving data from two columns I can't use list<string> as its return type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Tuple`

```
var clglist = new List<Tuple<int,string>>(from a in objYaphie.TblYP_CollegeProfile 
                               where a.SchoolName.StartsWith(prefix) 
                               select Tuple.Create(a.CollegeId,a.SchoolName));
```

Or, to make it more readable you can create a custom type and return a list of that type instead.

Comment: Your solution leads to an error "System.Tuple`2[System.Int32,System.String] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor".